# Method never gets called

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is how I call the method:

```
 $.ajax({ url: "MyController/Mymethod", type: "POST", data: { file: file.files[0] } })
```

And here is the method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Mymethod(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/images/location"), "petko.jpg");
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

file: file.files[0] is of type File. The method never gets called. Why?

Comment: use firebug and see what url it is calling. put a breakpoint in your code to see whether that method is executing

Comment: what is `file.files[0]` what is `file` and from where he did he come from? If you really want help, show the full code, it's not a sharades game...

Comment: @gdoron file is the browse button. file.files[0] is what is selected via the browse button.

Comment: Try to remove the data part of the `ajax` request, it looks wrong to me, see if it helps you.

Comment: @gdoron It doesn't help.

Comment: See in the FireBug console what going on with the request, what's the url, status of it... Anyway I give up. Good Luck!

Comment: @Srcee : Use firebug and see which url is being called in the ajax call.  I guess you have a wrong path.

Comment: I think he is trying to upload a file via ajax, and AFAIK that is not possible. You need a full postback to post files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I know that the question is asking why your method never gets called, how are you populating file.files? If this is a input of type file on your page, the upload doesn't occur until the form is submitted, so using your method, it will never post the file to your controller anyways.

Javascript does not have access to the file system due to security reasons. If you're trying to do an ajaxy file upload, you may want to look into Flash based uploaders such as [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by providing an error function on your AJAX call so you can get some idea about what's happening on the client side.  Example:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: "MyController/Mymethod", 
  type: "POST", 
  data: { file: file.files[0] },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert( textStatus + ": " + errorThrown );
  }
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert( "success: " + textStatus );
  }
});
```

I assume you've already set a breakpoint inside your controller to verify that it's actually not getting called.